# How to merge an array with duplicate keys with array merge?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge, array-unique

```
$cat1=array( "_id"=>new MongoId("562918fc2bad8c345d000029"),"name"=>"Category Two");


$cat2=array("_id"=>new MongoId("562918e62bad8c445d000029"),
"name"=>"Category One");

$categories=array();

$categories=array_merge($cat1,$cat2);

print_r($categories);
```

but it returns as follow

```
 array("_id"=>new MongoId("562918e62bad8c445d000029"),
"name"=>"Category One")
```

I tried array_unique too

```
array_unique(array_merge($cat1,$cat2))
```

**But result was same as above**

I know its not merging both array because both have same array keys.
Instead its merging second into a first array, But how can I merge both arrays so it will look like following.

```
array(array( "_id"=>new MongoId("562918fc2bad8c345d000029"),"name"=>"Category Two"),array("_id"=>new MongoId("562918e62bad8c445d000029"),
    "name"=>"Category One"));
```

Have a look at live code
http://viper-7.com/Oaa4zL

Comment: what result you want?

Comment: It should be merged like the last one.. I have mentioned it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know how many categories will be there, then you can simply push them to the array.

```
$allCat = array();
$allCat[] = $cat1;
$allCat[] = $cat2;
.
.
.
$allCat[] = $catN;

print_r($allCat);
```

Comment: Yes it is. It pushes category array to allCat array.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it manually and add them both to an array:

```
print_r(array(
    $cat1,
    $cat2
));
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to merge them:

```
$categories[] = array("_id"=>new MongoId("562918fc2bad8c345d000029"),
                      "name"=>"Category Two");

$categories[] = array("_id"=>new MongoId("562918e62bad8c445d000029"),
                      "name"=>"Category One");
```